# Dynamically declaring number of buttons in a for loop in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way to dynamically declare a certain number of UIButtons based on the number of iterations in a for loop?

the actual number would be passed in from the user or based on an array length

so pseudo-code would be

```
for num in total{
   //declare a UIbutton with a unique name 
}
```

Comment: use an array. you dont need unique names

Comment: yea I've been googling around after i posted the question and david are definitely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **UITableView** the best way to accomplish this is using the table own behavior to populate its cells automatically with your source date (array, dictionaries, etc) even with data gathered from external sources like a REST service.

The way to do this is creating a custom cell with each outlet and point them to your sources.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I think this is called metaprogramming and that swift doesn't have it yet :(

edit: looks like i was way overthinking things. this is actually fairly straightforward if i think about it without looping

Comment: would it be too complicated to somehow integrate some obj-c? basically i'm pulling in a contact's phone numbers from AddressBook so the user can select one to call. I thought it would be more elegant to just generate buttons based on the length of the array containing the numbers. Is the only way right now to hardcode a max?

Comment: You can do that with UITableView and custom cell, you just have to get each number from your source and update the button with the number. Each cell will be created with an individual number in your source for each contact.

Comment: good idea. i also found this https://github.com/arled/SwiftDynamicButtons/blob/master/SwiftDynamicButtons/SwiftDynamicButtons/ViewController.swift

Comment: @DaveGomez you wanna submit an answer so i can close this question out?